# Loop through each child of my parent jstree node

Tags: jquery, jstree

first posting here.

Having created a new jstree node and used a dialog to collect additional info, I am trying to do some validation against attributes from other siblings. But I cant figure out how to best loop though the siblings

```
   // get the list of children of the parent
   var siblings = $.jstree._reference(data.rslt.parent)._get_children("li");
```

this returns an array of the ten expected children, but I can not usefully look through them!

```
  siblings[0] // has no attr() method.
```

How do I best loop through siblings?

Comment: Could you provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry took ages to figure jsfiddle out! Have a look at [http://jsfiddle.net/qEE6L/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/qEE6L/23/). I guess the issue boils down to the var siblings, shown above, which returns an array of ??? for which there is an attr() method. Yet siblings[0] has no attr() method. The jstree documentation has many functions returning "JQuery extended LI elements" and others return "LI element" what is the difference?

Comment: jsTree is not working in your sample jsfiddle.

Comment: Hmm. Yes the fiddle appears to have problems. Works fine in Safari and on the Firefox/Centos machine I did all the work on, as well as a Firefox/Windows-XP machine I have to hand. However it fails with Firefox on my Mac and IE under Windows-XP. Haven't a clue why. Firefox/Mac+firebug reports 'TypeError: $(...).bind(...).bind(...).jstree' is not a function. Is this what you saw? Do you have a best practice example of setting up a jstree example within fiddle.